# cucumber JVM: How to run a scenario for another feature in a before hook

Tags: cucumber

I have a feature file with a scenario for creating a repo in a certain tool. I have commented out certain items for security reasons. This is not important.

- The `@CreateRepo` scenario tests steps for creating a repo
- The `@CreateBranch` scenario tests steps for creating a branch
- As shown below, `@CreateBranch` repeats all the same steps at the start of the scenario for creating a repo. It looks ugly and duplicates steps.
- I would like to be able to run `@CreateRepo` in a before hook in the step defs file for CreateBranch rather than having to duplicate all the same steps for creating a repo. *Is this possible?*

---

Feature file 1:

```
  Feature: Create a repository in {hidden}

  Background:
    Given I sign into {hidden} on 'node1' as the 'root' user using password: 'password'

  @CreateRepo
  Scenario: Administrator creates a new repository through {hidden} UI.
    When I click on the {hidden} icon on the Navigation bar
    Then I should be on the {hidden} page
    When I create a public project called {hidden}
    Then the repo {hidden} should be {hidden content}
    Then On 'node1' I follow the steps for creating a new repository
    When I clone {hidden} to 'node2'
    Then I check {hidden} on 'node2' has branch 'master'**
```

---

Feature File 2:

```
Feature: Create a branch for a project in {hidden}
    @CreateBranch
    Scenario: Administrator creates a new repository through {hidden} UI.
    When I click on the {hidden} icon on the Navigation bar
    Then I should be on the {hidden} page
    When I create a public project called {hidden}
    Then the repo {hidden} should be {hidden content}
    Then On 'node1' I follow the steps for creating a new repository
    When I clone {hidden} to 'node2'
    Then I check {hidden} on 'node2' has branch 'master'**
    When I click on the '{hidden}' link
    And I click on the '{hidden}' link
    When I select '{hidden}' from the {hidden} list
    And I click on the '{hidden}' for {hidden} button
    When I click the '{hidden}' button on {hidden} page
    Then I should be on the '{hidden}' page
```

---

Step definition file for feature file 2:

```
@Before("@CreateBranch")
public static void beforeCreateBranch() throws Exception{

  //Run @CreateRepo scenario somehow...

}
```